# Parallelizing with openmp makes memory leak

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, memory-leaks, openmp, valgrind

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    int a;
    int *arr;
    a = 3;
    arr = new int[a];
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        arr[i] = i;

    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

When I test this simple code with valgrind, it saids:

```
==2606== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2606==     in use at exit: 3,360 bytes in 7 blocks
==2606==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 3 frees, 108,892 bytes allocated
==2606== 
==2606== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2606==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2606==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2606==      possibly lost: 912 bytes in 3 blocks
==2606==    still reachable: 2,448 bytes in 4 blocks
==2606==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Am I misunderstanding openmp or memory allocation usage?

Without "#pragma omp parallel for", it doesn't make any issues.

UPDATE

```
==2682== 912 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 4 of 5
==2682==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2682==    by 0x40149DA: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:286)
==2682==    by 0x40149DA: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:532)
==2682==    by 0x4DE4322: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:622)
==2682==    by 0x4DE4322: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:660)
==2682==    by 0x4A4FDEA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==2682==    by 0x4A478E0: GOMP_parallel (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==2682==    by 0x109184: main (main.cpp:10)
```

This is what --leak-check-full says.

Comment: Without "#pragma omp parallel for", it doesn't make any issues.

Comment: If you want add more context to your question, you should do so with an [edit]. Comments are transient

Comment: Valgrind isn't saying that there is a memory leak. It just says that there is some memory for which it couldn't be sure ("possibly lost"). "still reachable" isn't an issue anyway. Not all memory needs to be explicitly freed before ending the program. OpenMP will itself also be using some memory, which is probably where these allocations are from.

Comment: So is it ok to use with possible leakage? Or do I have to add something to free openmp memory?

Comment: And what does `--leak-check=full` say?

Comment: Just updated it to the question.

Comment: And if you take these keywords and look them up on a search engine, you'll find https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36298